# Can't push/install APK but can push txt files

Tags: android, adb

currently I am trying to install a signed apk for testing on other emulators.
Right now I am stuck at even trying to install the apk on my fist emulator. Installing via Android Studio works fine.

Now I want to be able to push the apk file via adb on the emulator

I tried (in the folder where I have installed adb-tools):

```
adb install forEmulator\test.apk
```

and

```
adb push forEmulator\test.apk /sdcard/test.apk
```

each time I try this, it says:

```
* daemon started successfully*
protocol failure
```

and in android studio in the debugging status line it says sth like:

```
ASyncSocketServer99:Error when accepting HostConnection
```

if I try to push just a txt file on the sdcard like so

```
adb push forEmulator\text.txt /sdcard/text.txt
```

it works fine

the other methods I found on stack Overflow till now, didn't help me:

I am working on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with kill and start ADB manulay to resolve your issue.

**Android stop or start `adb` from command line**

Sometimes your android emulator might fails to connect eclipse DDMS tool and ask for `adb` to start manually. In that case you can start or stop the `adb` using the command prompt.

Open the cmd from **Start ⇒ run ⇒ cmd** and execute these commands.

Before you execute the commands in CMD make sure that you added the adb tool to your Environment Variables path.

Killing adb

```
adb kill-server
```

Starting adb

```
adb start-server
```

Comment: Working with android studio and already tried this. Did not work for me.